# Using function from another package in Android

Tags: java, android, plugins

I continue my previous topic related to the way to implement plugins in Android.

Well, I have, for example, in the class Main function setBackgroundColor(Color color). Can I now use it in a plugin? I do not want to share the main application code, but I want to when you call the function setBackgroundColor() of the plugin effect was the same, I invoke it from the main application.

The only thing I do not think now is the interface, something like:

```
public interface IPlugin {
    public void init();
    public void destroy();
    public void stop();
}
```

However, I do not know how to continue.

Please explain

Comment: What do you mean? Do you like to hide the implementation details in a not-public method?

Comment: For example I've got setColor() function in main application. Now, I want to use this function in another package (different app), like simple API. However,  I don't want share main application code.

Comment: Export it in an utility jar, referenced by both apps

Comment: But if such a file .JAR is safe, that is, if anyone can decode the source?

Comment: Of course yes, but this also happens if it is inside your Main app. Maybe are you searching a way to obfuscate your code?

Comment: In that case, yes, because I want to make sure that no one will decode the source, even if it will be a source of incomplete or encrypted.